# Android Programming: How can I add a text view on the screen each time I press a button on the screen?

Tags: android, button, textview

I'm new to android programming and am wondering if anyone can help me on this one:
How can I add a textView on the screen each time I press a button on the screen?

The button is already generated from the XML.  However, the textview need to be produced in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("Added tv");
layout.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce any view at runtime by doing a process like this.

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.common_list)
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("sample text");
ll.addView(tv);

setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: Sorry to be a noob... but what does "common_list" refer to?

Comment: common_list is the xml that you are currently setting in setContentView();.